# Regex Look Ahead

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Today for a project I was trying to make use of regular expression and learnt about groups and how to use them. I am using [this](http://www.regexr.com/) site to test it.The problem is that whenever I write the following regex:

> (?=\S*\d)

, the site gives me an error : `the expression can match 0 characters and therefore can match infinitely.`

while this doesn't throw any error :

> (?=\S*\d)(\S{6,16})

can anyone explain to me what is the meaning of the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because look aheads are assertions and they don't consume any characters.

```
(?=\S*\d)
```

When you write regex like this, it ***checks*** if it contains zero or more non spaces followed by a digit. But these characters are not consumed by the regex engine. And the pointer remains at the same position.

**Example**

```
 hello123
|
This is the initial position of pointer. It the checking starts from here

hello123
|
(?=\S*\d). Here it matches \S

hello123
 |
 (?=\S*\d)

This continues till

hello123
       |
     (?=\S*\d) Now the assertion is matched. The pointer backtracks to the position from where it started looking for regex.

 hello123
|
Now you have no more pattern to match. For the second version of the regex, the matching then begins from this postion
```

---

So what is the difference with

```
(?=\S*\d)(\S{6,16})
```

Here,

- `(?=\S*\d)` This part does the checking. I repeat again, this part doesn't consume any characters, it just checks.
- `(\S{6,16})` This part does the consumption of characters in the input string. That is it consumes at minimum of `6` non space characters and maximum of `16` characters.

Comment: Oh, that explains a lot, i thought the job of look ahead is to find the match and stop at the position where the match has been found. So this means that assertions can't be used alone since they only perform a check and return back to the start position. We need a regex that also consumes characters .

Comment: @JaymitDesai You got it. It performs just as the name suggest. Looks ahead if match occurs. Looking doesn't mean taking up :)